# Why is 'to' omitted after listen in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

The text to which you will listen is a combination of extracts ....

Comment: ...because "to" is already used before "which". You wouldn't use the preposition twice in this context. Another way of writing this sentence is "The text which you will listen to is a combination of extracts." Or "You will listen to the text. The text is a combination of extracts."

Comment: "This is the cave in which there is at least a million of bats." See how a preposition can take one of several possible places in a sentence: http://myenglishgrammar.com/lesson-6-prepositions/8-positions-of-preposition-in-the-sentence.html

Comment: Related: "Position of prepositions in questions and clauses"  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71866/14666

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have omitted the word 'to'. It appears earlier in the sentence after text. I also think both positions for 'to' are grammatically correct. The meaning is the same whether you say 'the text to which you will listen' or 'the text which you will listen to'. The latter is probably more common today. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, so one or the other but not both. The text to which you will listen to is ...

Comment: How do you explain this grammatically?

Comment: @Angela It's called 'fronting'. The preposition "to" has been placed in the front position along with its complement, rather than after the verb.